# How was nudity treated in Hinduism

Tags: puranas, history, dress

Is there any mention of attire for women/men in any ancient texts ?

How was nudity treated in Hinduism ?

Did other religion deeply influence the people of India ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Is there any mention of attire for women/men in any ancient texts ?**

> **paṭṭa-vastra, alaṅkāre, samarpiyā sakhī-kare,
>   sūkṣma-śukla-vastra-paridhāna kṛṣṇa lañā kāntā-gaṇa, kailā
>   jalāvagāhana, jala-keli racilā suṭhāma**
>
> “All the gopīs entrusted their silken garments and ornaments to the
>   care of their friends and then put on fine white cloth. Lord Kṛṣṇa,
>   taking His beloved gopīs with Him, bathed and performed very nice
>   pastimes in the water of the Yamunā. [paṭṭa-vastra](https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/antya/18/83) — silk garments;

Next

> **suvalita hasta, pada, kamala-nayāna paṭṭa-vastra śire, paṭṭa-vastra
>   paridhāna**
>
> He had beautifully formed hands, arms and legs, and eyes like lotus
>   flowers. He wore a silk cloth, with a silk turban on His head.
>   [paṭṭa-vastra](https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/adi/5/185) — silk garments;

Next

> **sei mleccha-madhye eka parama gambhīra kāla vastra pare sei, — loke
>   kahe ‘pīra’**
>
> Among the Muslims was a grave person who was wearing a black dress.
>   People called him a saintly person. [kāla vastra](https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/madhya/18/185) — black garments;

Or

> **ṭhākurera bhāṇḍāre āra āmāra bhāṇḍāre citra-vastra-kiṅkiṇī, āra
>   chatra-cāmare**
>
> “Take as many printed cloths, small bells, umbrellas and cāmaras as
>   there are in my storehouse and in the Deity’s storehouse. [citra-vastra](https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/madhya/14/109)
>   — printed cloth;

**How was nudity treated in Hinduism?**

If you refer the following instances then you can conclude that it wasn't considered as a proud moment but at the same time it has been related to as a tool to fulfill your desire.

> **taṁ dṛṣṭvā vrīḍitā devyo  vivastrāḥ śāpa-śaṅkitāḥ vāsāṁsi paryadhuḥ
>   śīghraṁ  vivastrau naiva guhyakau**
>
> Upon seeing Nārada, the naked young girls of the demigods were very
>   much ashamed. Afraid of being cursed, they covered their bodies with
>   their garments. But the two sons of Kuvera did not do so; instead, not
>   caring about Nārada, they remained naked. [refer](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/10/6)

Or

> **tan-mātā koṭarā nāma  nagnā makta-śiroruhā puro ’vatasthe kṛṣṇasya
>    putra-prāṇa-rirakṣayā**
>
> Just then Bāṇāsura’s mother, Koṭarā, desiring to save her son’s life,
>   appeared before Lord Kṛṣṇa naked and with her hair undone. [Refer](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/63/20)

Or

> **yūyaṁ vivastrā yad apo dhṛta-vratā  vyagāhataitat tad u deva-helanam
>   baddhvāñjaliṁ mūrdhny apanuttaye ’ṁhasaḥ  kṛtvā namo ’dho-vasanaṁ
>   pragṛhyatām**
>
> [Lord Kṛṣṇa said:] You girls bathed naked while executing your vow,
>   and that is certainly an offense against the demigods. To counteract
>   your sin you should offer obeisances while placing your joined palms
>   above your heads. Then you should take back your lower garments. [Refer](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/22/19)

Or

> **tān vilokyāmbikā devī  vivāsā vrīḍitā bhṛśam bhartur aṅkāt samutthāya
>    nīvīm āśv atha paryadhāt**
>
> When the goddess Ambikā saw the great saintly persons, she was very
>   much ashamed because at that time she was naked. She immediately got
>   up from the lap of her husband and tried to cover her breast. [Refer](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/1/30)

**Did other religion deeply influence the people of India ?**

History has ample sources to prove the invasions by the Muslims rulers as well as the Britishers/Dutch/Portuguese/French and this happened for centuries, the impact is clearly visible in many states of India where they ruled.

Comment: Also note that these are verses from Purana and later period literature. **Is there references regarding this, in pre-purana period literature (Veda, Brahmsutra,Mahabharat(includes Gita),Ramayana etc?** I have not found any.

Answer (score 0):

Nudity is considered shameful for women as per [this chapter](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_126.html) of harivamsa :

> *lambamAnA mahAbhAgA bhAgo devyAstathAShTAmaH | chitrA kanakashaktistu sA cha nagnA sthitAntare ||2-126-23*
> *The tall and highly illustrious goddess, born from the eighth part of goddess pArvatI, also known as chitrA and kanakashakti, **stood
> naked** between kR^iShNa and kumara (guha).*
>
> *athAntarAtkumArasya devIM dR^iShTvA mahAbhujaH | parA~Nmukhastato vAkyamuvAcha madhusUdanaH ||2-126-24*
> *Seeing the goddess between him and kumara (guha), the one with great arms (kR^iShNa), the slayer of madhu (kR^iShNa), **lowering his
> head**, said these words:*
>
> *shrIbhagavAnuvAcha apagachChApagachCha tvaM dhiktvAmiti vacho.abravIt | kimevaM kuruShe vighnaM nishchitasya vadhaM prati ||2-126-25*
> *The auspicious lord (kR^iShNa) said:
> **Go away! Go away! Shame!** Saying these words, kR^iShNa asked: Why are you creating this obstacle in the killing of one, whose death is
> decided?*
>
> *vaishampAyana uvAcha shrutvaivaM vachanaM tasya koTAvI tu tadA vibhoH | naiva vAsaH samAdhatte kumAraparirakShaNAt ||2-126-26*
> *vaishampAyana said: O lord (O janamejaya)! Hearing the words said by kR^iShNa, the goddess koTavI, did **not wear any dress**, for
> protecting kumara (guha).*